# OpenLayers and MapServer

Tags: openlayers, mapserver

I have the following code:

```
var layern2 = new OpenLayers.Layer.MapServer("Tech",
                "ServerPathTo_mapserv.exe",
                {
                    map: "ServerPathTo_My.map"
                },
                {
                    isBaseLayer: false,
                    layer: "Layer1",
                    version: "1.1.1",
                    transparent: "true",
                    visibility: true
                });
```

That does not render a non-transparent layer without images (all titles are rendered with a missing image icon on the upper left corner).

But the following code does render everything in the correct way:

```
var layern2 = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS("Tech",
                  "ServerPathTo_mapserv.exe?map=ServerPathTo_My.map&REQUEST=getmap&VERSION=1.1.1&LAYERS=Layer1&FORMAT=PNG", { layers: 'Layer1', TRANSPARENT: 'TRUE' });
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: This is javascript. Don't know why this is off-topic here and more suitable in super user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 2d argument are options for the MapServer's layer, and the 3rd argument are options for the OpenLayers's layer.

Try:

```
var layern2 = new OpenLayers.Layer.MapServer("Tech",
                "ServerPathTo_mapserv.exe",
                {
                    map: "ServerPathTo_My.map",
                    layer: "Layer1",
                    version: "1.1.1",
                    transparent: "true"
                },
                {
                    isBaseLayer: false,
                    visibility: true
                });
```

Comment: Did not render OK... I'm lost... Do I need to specify the projection?

Comment: if the OpenLayers.Layer.WMS works, why do you need the OpenLayers.Layer.MapServer?